# Saving only Last id of json response

Tags: android, json, android-spinner, android-json

This is my code for spinner dropdown which populates from server.Json response is like that

```
[{"ServiceId":"1","ServiceName":"AC"},
{"ServiceId":"5","ServiceName":"Plumbing"},
{"ServiceId":"27","ServiceName":"Others"}]
```

I am trying to send service id for ref. of corresponding service name to database but till now only last service id save in database.I.e. Service id not getting with their corresponding service name.How to resolve this?

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout_adapter, R.id.txt, listItems);
//        adapter.add("Select Service");
//        service_need.setAdapter(adapter);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String stuff1 = bundle.getString("local");
        autoCompView.setText(stuff1);

        String name = bundle.getString("name");

        adapter.add(name);
        service_need.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void registerUser() {

        final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        final String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("customerId", "Default_Value"));


        final String customer_id =value.toString().trim();
        final String username = editname.getText().toString().trim();
        final String house = houseNo.getText().toString().trim();
        final String local_area = autoCompView.getText().toString().trim();
        final String service = obj.getBytes().toString().trim();
        final String mobile_no = mobile.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email_id = email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String prob = problem.getText().toString().trim();



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        hidePDialog();
                        try {
                            //String result="";
                            //Do it with this it will work
                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject person = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String excep = person.getString("Exception");
                                String message1 = person.getString("Message");
                                String job = person.getString("JobNo");

                                if (excep.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    editname.setText("");
                                    // if email and mb is valid than login

                                    Intent i1 = new Intent(Form.this, Suceessful.class);
                                    i1.putExtra("job_id", job);
                                    startActivity(i1);
                                    finish();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, excep.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, message1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Toast.makeText(Form.this, job.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Form.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(CUSTOMERID,customer_id);
                params.put(USERNAME, username);
                params.put(HOUSENO, house);
                params.put(LOCALITY, local_area);
                params.put(SERVICE, obj);
                params.put(MOBILE, mobile_no);
                params.put(EMAIL, email_id);
                params.put(PROBLEM, prob);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }



    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        BackTask bt = new BackTask();
        bt.execute();
    }

    private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ArrayList<String> list;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            list = new ArrayList<>();

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://my_url/GetServiceList");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                // Get our response as a String.
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                is.close();
                //result=sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // add interviewee name to arraylist
                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("ServiceName"));
//                    list.add(jsonObject.getString("ServiceId"));
                    obj =jsonObject.getString("ServiceId");


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            listItems.addAll(list);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

 }
```

Log

```
09-01 14:21:41.243 5800-6053/com.enventpc_03.service99 I/System.out: URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyBdNoHzzo8PlGtv8Xa96uMZdKJbv6N8m8Q&components=country:in&components=administrative_area_level_3:lucknow&input=ddfss
09-01 14:21:41.643 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"AC","ServiceId":"1"}
09-01 14:21:41.653 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Plumbing","ServiceId":"5"}
09-01 14:21:41.673 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Refrigerator","ServiceId":"3"}
09-01 14:21:41.683 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Appliances","ServiceId":"7"}
09-01 14:21:41.763 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"RO","ServiceId":"21"}
09-01 14:21:42.363 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Electrical","ServiceId":"6"}
09-01 14:21:42.393 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Mobile","ServiceId":"4"}
09-01 14:21:42.663 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Computers","ServiceId":"9"}
09-01 14:21:42.693 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Tablets","ServiceId":"8"}
09-01 14:21:42.693 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Home Security","ServiceId":"22"}
09-01 14:21:42.704 5800-6131/com.enventpc_03.service99 D/jsonObject: {"ServiceName":"Others","ServiceId":"27"}
09-01 14:21:43.273 302-424/system_process A/NetworkStats: problem reading network stats
                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
                                                              at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
                                                              at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271)
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771)
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610)
                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
                                                           Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                              at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
                                                              at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
                                                              at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
                                                              at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610) 
                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60) 
                                                           Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                              at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                              at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
                                                              at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78) 
                                                              at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272) 
                                                              at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1271) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128) 
                                                              at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610) 
                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Please share the full class code. I presume you have a loop ?

Comment: This is complete code regard with service name and service id.No other loop have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize list inside the for loop this is call by reference problem. So do the following :

```
....
// parse json data
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        // add interviewee name to arraylist
        list.add(jsonObject.getString("ServiceName"));
        list.add(jsonObject.getString("ServiceId"));
        obj =jsonObject.getString("ServiceId");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

Comment: Still have same issue with one more is issue that ,spinner not populate all data.

Comment: @Adi I am sorry but i am not able to see the declaration of listItems inside the inner class

Comment: I have just only change the code according to ur answer in my ide

Comment: Please use logs for value of jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i); and share it

Comment: I have not enough idea about these kind of dubug..But I' trying like that Log.d("jsonObject", "jsonObject");

Comment: And it prints same name(jsonObject) multiple times(I.e. no of times loops excutes)

Comment: You are printing out the string "jsonObject".  Do the logging like follows: Log.d("jsonObject",  jsonObject.toString());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122377/discussion-between-adi-and-gaurav4sarma).